# Pass arguments from array in php to constructor

Tags: php, arrays, function, constructor, arguments

Normally, if I want to pass arguments from $myarray to $somefunction I can do this in php using

```
call_user_func_array($somefunction, $myarray);
```

However this does not work when the function one wishes to call is the constructor for an object. For fairly obvious reasons it does not work to do:

```
$myobj = new call_user_func_array($classname, $myarray);
```

is there something fairly elegant that *does work* ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use the Reflection API:

- [`ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php) — Creates a new class instance from given arguments.

Example:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$foo = $reflector->newInstanceArgs(array('foo', 'bar'));
```

Comment: In PHP 5.6 you can also use argument unpacking via the ``...`` or splat operator : http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat

Comment: Quick and easy! I was already using the Reflection API in my new package loader module, and this gives me a way to account for any number of arguments in future versions.