# __call magic creating new classes in PHP

Tags: php, class, constructor, call

I am using the __call magic within some of my mvc code to produce an autoloadable forms framework but I have ran into a problem I am hoping some one on here might have a work around for.

The __call magic takes two paramters: $methodName and $arguments. The arguments come back as an array of args which you called. Normally this function is called on methods you can do as such so feed these arguments into a function:

```
call_user_func_array($methodName, $arguments);
```

And this will propogate the methods signature with the arguments. I am trying to do something a little more complex. I am attempting to propogate a classes constructor the same way, through being able to send maybe a imploded comma deliminenated array of the arguments into the classes constructor or just sending the args in directly but both of these do not produce the required result. When I send an imploded array down into the constructor PHP thinks it's a string and when I send the array it thinks it's an array.

This is the code I am using atm:

```
public function __call($method, $args){

    return $this->init_element(new $method($args['name'], $args['value'], $args['opts']));

}
```

What if I had 4 arguments to pass down though? Is there a way I can get it to dynamically fill the constructor just like you can for a function using call_user_func_array()?

I could use an attributes() function to do this but I would really like to be able to do it like I can with functions.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass arguments from array in php to constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395914/pass-arguments-from-array-in-php-to-constructor) - Use Reflection.

Comment: Yes this might work, I'll try it out and see if it works thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's reflection classes: (http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php)

`$obj = new ReflectionClass( $classname );`

then

`$ins = $obj->newInstanceArgs( $arguments );`

or

`$ins = $obj->newInstance( );`

Comment: Whats the speed of this function? I know reflection can be very slow?

Comment: @Sammaye benchmark it in your app if you think it can make a significant slowdown

Comment: As I get a test built up and that I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294582/php-5-reflection-api-performance which states that so long as I'm careful and only have it in request/dispatch I should be ok since the __call is a dispatcher I shouldn't really feel the strain only thing is it will dispatch every time I create a new form element. I'm gonna get a benchmark running and see what happens.

Comment: @Sammaye chances are, your __call invocations without the Reflection code are not exactly fast either. Magic methods come with slowdown too. The big question is will it matter?

Comment: If I'm already using a _call no...so Long as I never need to make a truely huge form...but then again PHP can handle a lot on the right server so it might be pefectly fine I might just be paraniod over nothing.

Comment: Decided to go with this one it was about 1ms quicker than call_user_func_array hopefully it wont cause too much of a strain since I only use this for form element making and nothing else and only once each element then :). thanks for the info :)

Answer (score -1):

I saw the following somewhere around the web:

```
 call_user_func_array(array($obj, '__construct'), $args);
```

Comment: Could some one explain why this has been marked down since as far as I can tell this is not only the same speed (if not a little faster) than reflection and there does not appear to be any real security side effects from it. Could some one tell me why this has been marked down?

Comment: @Sammaye Wasn't me who downvoted, but I'd say it was dv'ed because it doesn't work. Calling `__construct` on an existing instance is pointless and providing the classname instead of `$obj` will produce a warning and no instance. If you want `call_user_func_array` give classes a static factory method and call that.

Comment: Ah yea this might be good I'ma need to benchmark between the two.

Comment: I think that `$obj` is the name of that class. PHP typically handles invocation of class members like this. Example: `usort($someArray, array('SomeClass', 'someStaticSortFunc'))`.