# PHP custom class loader

Tags: php, class, classloader, instantiation

i made a custom class loader function in php
something like..

```
load_class($className,$parameters,$instantiate);
```

its supposed to include the class and optionally instantiate the class specified

the problem is about the parameters. ive been trying to pass the parameters all day
i tried

```
load_class('className',"'param1','param2'",TRUE);
```

and

```
load_class('className',array('param1','param2'),TRUE);
```

luckily nothing works xD
is it possible to pass the params?
i even tried..

```
$clas = new MyClass(array('param1','param2'));
```

here it is..

```
function load_class($class, $param=null, $instantiate=FALSE){
    $object = array();
    $object['is_required'] = require_once(CLASSES.$class.'.php');
    if($instantiate AND $object['is_required']){
        $object[$class] = new $class($param);
    }
    return $object;
}
```

Comment: You might want to show your load_class function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass arguments from array in php to constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395914/pass-arguments-from-array-in-php-to-constructor)

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: yes..it says that the parameters ($param) for the constructor of the class is not passed..

Comment: @Gordon i did try this too call_user_func_array(array($classname, '__construct'), $ArrayOfArgs);

Comment: @kapitan call_user_func does not work with constructors afaik. so you have to use the Reflection method as shown in the linked question.

Comment: yup i did..thanks anyway. i finally made it work. is this reflection method already a part of PHP or is it something like pear that needs to be installed?

Comment: @kapitan it's part of PHP. On a sidenote, instead of requiring the classes, you might also want to consider using `spl_autoload_register` to include classes into your code.

Answer (score 3):

if you are in PHP 5.x I really really recommend you to use [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). Prior to PHP 5.3 you should create sort of "namespace" (I usually do this with _ (underscore))

autoload allows you to include classes on the fly and if your classes are well designed the overhead is minimun.

usually my autoload function looks like:

```
<?php
function __autoload($className) {
    $base = dirname(__FILE__);
    $path = explode('_', $className);

    $class = strtolower(implode('/',$path));

    $file = $base . "/" . $class;       

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;      
    }
    else {
        error_log('Class "' . $className . '" could not be autoloaded');
        throw new Exception('Class "' . $className . '" could not be autoloaded from: '.$file); 
    }
}
```

this way calling

```
$car = new App_Model_Car(array('color' => 'red', 'brand' => 'ford'));
```

the function will include the class

> app/model/car.php

Comment: It is not wise to use __autoload() since it's been replaced by spl_autoload_register(). __autoload() Will be deprecated soon. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you should be using [__autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to just load classes as they are referenced and circumvent having to call this method manually.  This is exactly what __autoload() is for.